# API request with multiple body inputs

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel this is how I make an API with one single body item

```
$shops_categories=ShopsCategories::all()->where('title',$request->title);
```

how to request more than an item in the body for example title , email , password ?

Comment: You can pass array to `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent allows you to chain as many `where` as required. So you are able to do

```php
$shops_categories = ShopsCategories::where('title',$request->title)->where('email',$request->email)->where('password',$request->email)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```php
$cats = ShopsCategories::query()->where(['title' => $title, 'email'=>$email, 'name'=>$name]);
```

Comment: I want it in this same form 'title',$request->title

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are performing query operation in controller itself which is not recommended,please create an instance for the model and make a function call to model and in the model you can return like

```
return $this::where('id','=',$id)->get()
```

and also please try to avoid using text/string in where condition instead use id's  or unique values

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert request to array using all()

```
//$request->all() is same as ['title'=> 'my title', ...]

$shops_categories=ShopsCategories::where($request->all())->get();
```